# Will WIFI improve the network position accuracy on android?

Tags: android, geolocation

I am writing a small app to get the users position over network (no GPS). I have only GSM turned on and the position is not very accurate. I mean it is OK to get the city name. But I need something more accurate. If I turn on the WIFI, will the accuracy be increased?

How does it work? Will android send the list of available wifi (mac addresses?) How much data will be sent to the server to get the location?

Is there a document where I can read how geo location over network for android works?

Answer (score 1):

Turning on Wifi will give you better location accuracy since Google detects and analyses all the Wifi access points and then gives you a location nearer to the Wifi Access Points that you phone can see or scan.

**So, yes, turning on WiFi will increase your accuracy.**

You can read up this thread. I couldn't find an official one. With a little effort, I am sure you will find it somewhere.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1781468